# Overall predictive power (e.g. R2) for Bayesian Linear (Mixed) Models

Tags: r, bayesian, mixed-models, stan, rstan

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44693812/how-to-report-with-apa-style-a-bayesian-linear-mixed-models-using-rstanarm) question about journal reporting, I would like to know if there is any overall effect size indice for Bayesian models fitted using `stan_lmer`?

In the frequentist framework, there is for example the pseudo-R2 (computed by [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MuMIn/MuMIn.pdf) package) that returns the *marginal* (the proportion of variance explained by the fixed factor(s) alone) and the *conditional* (the proportion of variance explained by both the fixed and random factors) R2. Is there any equivalent that would help us quantify and qualify effects/predictive power size?

Thank you.

Comment: I've calculated effect sizes for Bayesian models using the BEST package, not sure if that will help you here with `stan_lmer`. There's a discussion [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90668/bayesian-analysis-of-contingency-tables-how-to-describe-effect-size) that might help.

Answer (score 2):

For `stan_lm` or `stan_glm` with `family = gaussian(link = "identity")`, you could calculate a posterior distribution of R-squared with

```
R2 <- rowSums(posterior_linpred(post)^2) / rowSums(posterior_predict(post)^2)
```

where `post` is the object returned by `stan_lm` or `stan_glm`. For `stan_lmer` or (equivalently) `stan_glmer` with `family = gaussian(link = "identity")` you could do something similar but have to take a position on what to do with the group-specific terms (i.e. `(1 | group)`). The `re.form` argument to `posterior_linpred` and `posterior_predict` gives you several options, but by default the group-specific terms are conditioned on. Alternatively, you could set (some of) them to zero or pass a `data.frame` with new group levels to integrate over (some of) the group-specific terms.